# Python fillna with dictionary values or keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where i am trying to fill in an existing column, but will settle for a new column.

```
The code i have tried is(which does not work): 

df1['NewCol1'] = df1['ID'].map(dict1.get(df1['Name'])) #but the code i would like to use is:
df1['ExistingColumn'] = df1['ID'].ifna().map(dict1.get(df1['Name'])) #i am trying to fill an existing column 
#the dictionary i am using is:
dict1 = {'Name':'ID'}
```

The dataframe i am working in looks something like this:

```
ID    Name   ExistingColumn
1     name1  id1
1     name2  id1
2     name3  id2
NA    name3  id2
NA    name2  id1
```

Also, if this can be done, is there a way to do this by referencing a dictionary by value and pulling back the key?

Comment: can you provide example of 1) your dictionary 2) your output dataframe.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have `fillna`

```
df.ID.fillna(df.Name.map(dict),inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It's interesting that i dont have to set this equal to a specific column and can just run the statement you provided!  This is great, I really appreciate the help as i have danced around/close to this answer for 5 hours